# How to troubleshoot 502 Bad Gateway after updating Discourse?

Tags: docker, nginx, discourse

I just updated Discourse by running the following after the server being at sleep for a few months.

```
cd /var/discourse
git pull
./launcher rebuild app
```

Now, when I open my Discourse URL, I get a Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error.

I know very little about Docker. How can I figure out what isn’t working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `./launcher rebuild app` again fixed the issue.